# Open multiple terminal but without closing the previous one using shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am starter in shell scripting.
I am trying to open 4 terminal using a script.
Here's the code

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
    echo $i
    if [ $i -eq 1 ]; then
        # xterm -e 
        xterm -e "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash"
        opensublime
    elif [ $i -eq 2 ]; then
        xterm -e "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash"
        openspark
    elif [ $i -eq 3 ]; then
        xterm -e "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash"
        openpycharm
    elif [ $i -eq 4 ]; then
        xterm -e "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash"
        runproject 8000
    fi

done
```

The problem is it is opening a new terminal but for second terminal I need to close first one. How I can avoid closing of previous terminal to open next one.

Complete Code

```
dpkg -s xterm  &> /dev/null
echo "Checking for Xterm"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Package  is installed!"
else
    echo "Package is not installed. Now installing package"
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get install xterm
    echo "Package  is NOW installed!"
fi

for i in 1 2 3 4
    do
        echo $i
        if [ $i -eq 1 ]; then
            xterm -e "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash" &
            opensublime
        elif [ $i -eq 2 ]; then
            xterm -e "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash" &
            openspark
        elif [ $i -eq 3 ]; then
            xterm -e "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash" &
            openpycharm
        elif [ $i -eq 4 ]; then
            xterm -e "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash" &
            runproject 8000
        fi
    done
```

openapps.sh

```
function opensublime() {
  cd "/opt/Sublime Text 2"
  eval "./sublime_text"
  cd 
}
function openpycharm() {
  cd "/home/akshay/Documents/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/bin"
  eval "./pycharm.sh"
  cd 
}
function openspark(){
  cd "/opt/Spark/"
  eval "./Spark"
  cd 
}
function runproject(){
  cd "wr_workspace/corporate_admin/"
  eval "source ../env/bin/activate"
  echo "starting server on port $1"
  eval  "python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:$1"
  deactivate
  cd
}
```

Comment: Should the `openspark` etc. commands be run _inside_ the terminals?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes

Comment: The `xterm` presence check in the complete version is not actually checking the result of the `dpkg` command, but of the `echo` command. And running `apt-get upgrade` means potentially a full system upgrade: running it in a script that is just supposed to ensure xterm is available is a bit excessive in my opinion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your script to not wait for the execution of a command to end before proceeding to the next command, add `&` to the end of the command line.

Also, you don't need a loop if you want to do a different thing each time around the loop. Just list the things you wish to do in sequence.

After a bit of back&forth in the comments, I understand you want the xterm to run a `bash` shell which should first source your `openapps.sh` script and then execute a function defined in the script. So something like this should work:

```
xterm -e bash -c "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; opensublime; bash" &
xterm -e bash -c "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; openspark; bash" &
xterm -e bash -c "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; openpycharm; bash" &
xterm -e bash -c "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; runproject 8000; bash" &
```

I'm not certain whether or not the ...`; bash` part is actually necessary, but I kept it just in case.

Your original commands had a few problems:

```
xterm -e "source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash" 
opensublime
```

This tells xterm to execute the command line `source /home/akshay/openapps.sh; bash`. But `xterm` is not a shell: it can only execute things that are actual executable files on disk. `source` is an internal command in Bourne-style shells, and so it does not exist as an executable file.

The `openapps.sh` script is sourced by the instance of `bash` within the xterm, but the commands `opensublime`/`openspark` etc. are attempting to call the functions of `openapps.sh` in a different shell instance, that does not necessarily have sourced `openapps.sh`, and so these commands may fail.

So, you'll need `xterm` to run a shell *within the new xterm window*, with a specified command line. `xterm -e bash -c "<commands>"`does that.

If you want to use your `opensublime`  and other functions, you'll need to run those in the same shell that sourced your `openapps.sh`, otherwise they are likely to just produce `command not found` error messages. And that's why those commands needed to be moved inside the double quotes.

`ulimit` settings and `export`ed environment variables can be propagated from a parent process through a non-shell child (`xterm` in this case) to a grandchild process (`bash` running within the `xterm`), but shell functions won't be passed this way; they'll need to be reloaded.

Comment: Added '&'. Now it is opening 4 terminals but saying 'opensublime: command not found' and same for openspark, openpycharm and for runproject. If i omit that '&' part then it opens the first terminal and also runs the command. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: In your original script, are the opensublime/openspark/etc. commands actually on the same line as the `xterm ...` commands?

Comment: yes. all commands are on same line of xterm

Comment: I have updated the complete code

Comment: What is the `/home/akshay/openapps.sh` script supposed to do? Is it necessary to run it before `opensublime` etc.? Are `opensublime`, `openspark`, `openpycharm` and `runproject` binary applications, scripts, or shell aliases or functions?

Comment: yes. I have defined functions opensublime, openspark, openpycharm, runproject in that file/script

Comment: added code of openapps.sh

Comment: the updated answer with one line command worked. Can you explain why that 1 liner worked but not multi line statement

Comment: Updated my answer.