# Opening multiple tiled terminals on startup

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminator

Related to

[Open multiple terminal but without closing the previous one using shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454880/open-multiple-terminal-but-without-closing-the-previous-one-using-shell-script)

How can multiple tiled terminals be opened on startup, each running a number of commands. For example:

```
++++++++++++++++
|  T1  |    T2 |
|      +++++++++
|      |    T3 | 
++++++++++++++++
```

In `T1`

```
$ mkdir tmp && cd tmp
$ sudo openvpn <conf>
```

In `T2`:

```
$ mkdir proj_dir && cd proj_dir
```

In `T3`:

```
$ <might need to do something here too>
```

Can this also be extended to opening tiled terminals on another desktop? Maybe this is a separate question.